# Efficiently find whether a string contains a group of characters (like substring but ignoring order)?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

What's the most efficient way to find whether a group of characters, arranged in a string, exists in a string in Python?

For example, if I have `string="hello world"`, and sub-string `"roll"`, the function would return true because all 4 letters in `"roll"` exist in `"hello world"`.

There's the obvious brute-force methodology, but I was wondering if there's an efficient Python specific way to achieve this.

**EDIT:** letters count is important. So for example `rollll` isn't included in `hello world` (only three l's).

Comment: Is the obvious brute-force methodology `set(string).issuperset(set("roll"))`?

Comment: Is this intended to be canonical? @muru Post it as an answer even if it is. Much better than `Counter`.

Comment: Do you care about numbers of letters? e.g. should `thefunc("hello world", "rollllllll")` be true or false?

Comment: `"hello world"` contains three `l's` so `"rolll"` should be included in `"hello world"`

Comment: @Abhijit fixed it thanks

Answer (score 16):

You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

substring_counts = Counter(substring)
text_counts = Counter(text)

if all(text_counts[letter] >= count for letter, count in substring_counts.items()):
    # All the letters in `substring` are in `count`
```

Comment: So in the end it was *still* `Counter` after all :P :)

Answer (score 14):

For a "contains" check, I'd usually pick sets:

```
set(string).issuperset(set(substring))
# or
set(string) >= set(substring)
```

I'm not sure of the complexity here, but [this page](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt) says that set construction and superset checking are both O(n), so this would be O(n+m), on par with [Daniel Pryden's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230845/2072269).

As noted by Kasramvd, you don't need to make the a set of the substring when using `issuperset`:

```
set(string).issuperset(substring)
```

Using `>=` still needs the conversion, though.

Comment: There is no need to convert the sub string to `set`.

Comment: @muru aren't sets limited to unique elements? Please see my clarification: EDIT: letters count is important. So for example rolll isn't included in hello world (only two l's).

Comment: @RoeeAdler I understand your point, but your example has a problem: "Hello world" has three l's; "world" has one too.

Comment: @RoeeAdler if letter count is important, `collections.Counter` is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Build a histogram of characters in each string and then you can verify whether every letter in the substring occurs in the larger string. Runtime is linear (`O(n + m)`) and space is proportional to the size of the alphabet.

This is a form of [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Note that `collections.Counter` is a histogram data structure, so the algorithm is roughly the same. Since `Counter` uses a hashtable, it has space complexity proportional to the number of items (letters) actually encountered, but with higher constant factors than a pigeonhole approach, so `Counter` is slightly less efficient, but unlikely to be noticeably so.

Comment: Daniel Pryden answer works well,It is especially good if you run multiple queries on the same string. But I think the answer can be made faster in most cases if instead of counting you simply check a Boolean, and keep the number of letters you encountered and if you encountered all letters you break
.

Comment: Indeed, O(n+m) is not very good if it actually takes time proportional to n despite the match being found in a much smaller initial sequence. There should be ways to fix this so that it's O(n'+m) where n' is the length of the minimal prefix needed for producing the result.

Comment: @hassanarafat: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you still need to build the histogram of the needle, to efficiently search through the haystack, right? If you have a histogram of the needle, then you can do an O(n) pass through the haystack and decrement the counts from the histogram along the way. If the histogram count reaches zero then it's a success; if you ever have fewer characters remaining in the haystack than total count remaining in the histogram then it's a failure.

Comment: My suggestion is simply an optimization in case you found all the letters before the end of the string, (BTW using my optimization means having to override default Histogram behavior , or implementing your own) this is especially helpful if the string is very long but has all the letters at the start.

Answer (score 5):

Use the concept of `Hashing`:

In python, `hashing` is implemented using `dict()`

```
hashmap = dict()
string = "hello world"
substring = "roll"
for char in string:
    if char in hashmap:
        hashmap[char] += 1
    else:
        hashmap[char] = 1

flag = 0    
for char in substring:
    if char in hashmap and hashmap[char] >= 1:
        hashmap[char] -= 1
    else:
        flag = 1
        break

if flag == 1:
    print False
else:
    print True
```

For the characters in string, we make a hashmap that keeps a record of the different characters available and their respective counts.

Next we iterate over the substring and find out if all the characters are available or not.. If available we decrement the count of that character in the hashmap and move forward. IF not present, then simply `break` out and print `False`..... So simple

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This method is about 4x faster than using `Counter` (they both operate at about 100k calls per second for somewhat long inputs).

Answer (score 4):

If you want efficiency, you can construct a `Counter` that counts all the letters in `string` and decrements these counts for each letter in `substring`. If any count is below 0, there are not enough instances of the character in `string` to create `substring`. This is an O(`string` + `substring`) algorithm.

```
from collections import Counter

def unordered_substring(string, substring):
    string_counter = Counter(string)

    for char in substring:
        string_counter[char] -= 1
        if string_counter[char] < 0:
            return False

    return True
```

In the case where `string` is long and `substring` will often be found, you can reverse the method to count the letters in `substring` and then iterate over `string`, breaking when all characters have been found.

```
def unordered_substring_long(string, substring):
    substring_counter = Counter(substring)
    total_count = sum(substring_counter.values())

    for char in string:
        if substring_counter[char] > 0:
            substring_counter[char] -= 1
            total_count -= 1
            if total_count == 0:
                return True

    return False
```

Comment: (If you want to be memory aware, create counters for the characters in the _group_ and decrease them for occurrences in the string.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this, which is `True` if and only if each character in `sub` exists in `s` as stated by the OP:

```
all(sub.count(i) <= s.count(i) for i in set(sub))
```

it's `True` if for every distinct character in `sub` there are at least as many of them in `s` as in `sub`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to loop over the sub string rather than the string itself. And as a more pythonic approach you can use a generator expression within `sum` by summing the number of ocurance of the sub strings letters within the main string. Then compare it with the length of sub-string:

```
sum(i in s for i in sub) == len(sub)
```

As you can see it's pretty much faster than the `counter` and `set` approach, when your string gets larger:

```
In [45]: s = "hello world"

In [46]: sub  = "roll"

In [47]: s *= 1000

In [48]: %timeit set(s).issuperset(sub)
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 µs per loop

In [53]: %timeit substring_counts = Counter(sub); text_counts = Counter(s); all(text_counts[letter] >= count for letter, count in substring_counts.items())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.21 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit sum(i in s for i in sub) == len(sub)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 739 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that pops to my mind is that you could easily take the individual character count of the original string and then take the character count of each sub-string. Then cross check with the character count of the original string to see if the number of characters from each type needed to create your sub-string is present or not. This is a very easy method to find if a given string is an anagram of another string. The same could be applied to your scenario.